# Does $(\Bbb{R}, +)$ admit an irreducible $2$-traversal?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, latin-square

For a given natural number $k$, I'm going to call a subset $T$ of the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$ a $k$-traversal if, for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align*}
k &= \operatorname{card} \{(a, b) \in T : a = x\} \\
&= \operatorname{card} \{(a, b) \in T : b = x\} \\
&= \operatorname{card} \{(a, b) \in T : a + b = x\}.
\end{align*}
It's not difficult to see that lines in the plane that aren't parallel to the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis, or the line $x + y = 0$ will be $1$-traversals (but are far from the only examples!). We can make $2$-traversals without difficulty by taking two disjoint $1$-traversals and unioning them. My question is,

> Is there a $2$-traversal that cannot be decomposed into the union of two $1$-traversals?

The idea of (irreducible) $k$-traversals is a concept from latin squares. I'm trying to consider the concept when applied to an (uncountably) infinite Latin square generated by the group $(\Bbb{R}, + )$.

This was a question that popped into my head years ago when attending a combinatorics conference. Combinatorics is not my forte, but it seemed like an interesting question, and I thought I'd share it.

Comment: Why the group theory tag?

Comment: @verret Ostensibly it's because this is a traversal on a latin square generated by a group. Though it's not a particularly interesting group, I suspect that the existence or non-existence of an irreducible $2$-traversal will have something to do with properties of the group.

Comment: What is stopping us from taking any 2-traversal, and expressing it as a disjoint union $I \cup I^c$, where $I$ is the 1-traversal formed by picking one point from each of the sets above?

Comment: @William I don’t think it’s anything so simple. Picking a point blindly from one set may make an over-abundance in another. What if you pick $(-2,2)$ for the first set when $x=-2$ and $(-1,1)$ for the second set when $x = 1$ (if $T$ happens to contain both points)? Then the cardinality of the third set would be too large when $x = 0$. Some axiom of choice argument may work, but I haven’t been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vincent's example... $T$ is the union of two graphs $y=\frac{|x-1|}{2}$ and $y=-\frac{|x+1|}{2}$.

[image: T]

Each vertical line meets $T$ in two points, one in the top graph and one in the bottom graph.
Each horizontal line meets $T$ in two points: either two in the top graph, or two in the bottom graph, or the two corners on the $x$-axis.
Each line of slope $-1$ meets $T$in two points, one in the top graph and one in the bottom graph.
Thus, $T$ is a $2$-traversal.

Next, we claim it is impossible to have $T = A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are $1$-traversals and $A \cap B = \varnothing$.  Indeed, consider the three points
$$
u:=\left(0,\frac12\right),\quad
v:=\left(2,\frac12\right),\quad
w:=\left(2,-\frac32\right).
$$

[image: B]

Now $A$ contains exactly one of the points $u,v$, since they are both on the line $y=\frac12$.  $A$ contains exactly one of the points $v,w$, since they are both on the line $x=2$.  And $A$ contains exactly one of the points $w,u$, since they are both on the line $x+y=\frac12$.  Impossible.

Comment: Thank you! Nice and clean.

Comment: Aaah, the $u, v, w$ part is really nice! No extra niceness condition needed. Very good!

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that this (or a variation) would work, but maybe I am overlooking something. It is definitely the union of two things, but they are not 1-traversals.

Take the union of the v-shape $y = |1/2(x-1)|$ and upside-down v-shape $y = -|1/2(x+1)|$.

Comment: What remains is: this is not a union of two $1$-traversals.  That does not seem easy.

Comment: hm yes. There could be some really weird 1-traversals out there...

Comment: It would be nice to have some 'niceness condition' in the definition of $k$-traversal, like being a countable union of curves $(x(t), y(t))$ for $x, y \colon (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. But then it is still hard